# Running a script asking for sudo permission from a keyboard shortcut xfce4

Tags: bash, debian, sudo

I have written a small script which basically change brightness of screen because keyboard shortcuts for brightness are not working. the bash script is as follows:
`#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/brightness`
and I added this line in sudoers file to prevent asking for password:
`kareem dhcppc2 = /home/kareem/bin/backlight.sh`
However this line seems wrong as it does ask for password.

After adding the command as a keyboard shortcut, pressing the shortcut doesn't make any response.

I know this seems to be a noob question, I am a bigger in writing scripting.

Comment: Your sudoers line seems to be incorrect. Here's how I managed to get it working on an Asus laptop (you can modify to your needs): [http://askubuntu.com/questions/644410/cannot-turn-on-keyboard-backlight/701145#701145](http://askubuntu.com/questions/644410/cannot-turn-on-keyboard-backlight/701145#701145)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but you seem to need to automatically enter your password for sudo...I wouldn't advise this, as it requires that you write your password in plain text, but...
I would use expect for this one...

```
spawn /home/kareem/bin/backlight.sh
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\n"
```

Hope that works...If it doesn't, just google how to use expect in bash.